# previous page styles until refresh

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm using different css.scss files for 2 pages in my rails app.
The issue is, when i'm going from one to another, new page weirldy obtain all styles from the previous one, until browser is refreshed.

Here is the code of one page:

```
<head>
<%= metamagic title: "Sample title", description: "Sample description", keywords: %w(key1 key2 key3) %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "posts", media: "all"  %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

And if commenting out the javascript_include_tag, everything works just fine

Are there any suggestions to deal with that problem?
Thank you for your time)

Comment: I bet you're using turbolinks :)

Comment: yes, the issue was in turbolinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely cause is turbolinks. If you have separate layouts on different pages, you will need to disable turbolinks on links that should cause a change in layout. Add a `data-no-turbolink` attribute to these links:

```
= link_to 'should change layouts', some_path, data: { no_turbolink: true }
```

This will force the full page to be loaded instead of just the content portion of the page.